# Как проверить включен ли у пользователя javascript?

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо проверить, включен ли у пользователя javascript и, если нет, то отправить его на страницу, где большими красными буквами написано, что нужно включить javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте тег `<noscript>`.
Пример [здесь](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/noscript)

Comment: Это немного не то, что мне нужно. Но это пойдет. Я сделал в главном контейнере style="visibility:hidden" и на загрузку body повесил обработчик, которые показывает контейнер. Таким образом, если javascript отключен, то главный контейнер не отображается, а отображается <nonscript>.